# New users editing questions

Tags: discussion, editing

In reviewing other user's edits, it seems like recently a lot of users with very low ratings (ie $\sim 100$) are editing other user's questions. I've seen quite a few edits are clearly wrong, such as turning a mixed effects model from

`y ~ x + (1 | ID)` to `y ~ x + (1 / ID)`

and other cases of adding "Thanks for the help guys" etc. to the end of a post.

I thought a minimum rating was required to edit other's posts?

Comment: If you could supply a link or two to such threads, it would help us determine what actually happened.

Comment: If I recall correctly, I believe the following was an example of a user with a low rating adding a "Thanks guys!" or something to the end of the original question (which I rejected). 

http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173121/kernel-density-estimation

Comment: This included an edit that was okay (I approved, but it really didn't help that much...) by a user with rating = 149. 

http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173141/confident-interval-negative

Comment: Perhaps this my misunderstanding; I thought that a minimum ranking of something like 500 was required, but I now see that all that is required is 100.

Comment: @gung no our edits were ships passing the night.  I started editing before your edit was committed.  When I started that text was deleted.  You deleted it and I didn't.  When I committed your edit it was ~20 sec after you finished.  [I couldn't rollback my suggested edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80933/301021), so I was stuck.  (I had that link handy because I looked it up after reading your edit.)

Comment: @Erik, oh I see that now. My apologies.

Comment: @gung  No worries.  I understand the confusion, and that is why I up-voted the request to allow rolling back edits on Meta. :)

Comment: @CliffAB I just realized that you linked to my edit in the comments above.

Comment: @Erik, ha, don't take it as insult. I had just thought that users needed a higher rating to edit posts and was confused why they were allowed to do so. That was just an example of what was confusing me.

Comment: @CliffAB Don't worry about it.  It takes more than that to make me feel insulted. I figured I was partly responsible for you asking this question when I read the title because I edited 4 or 5 questions earlier today based on the response to [this Meta question](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/2704/89026).

Comment: The rep needed to suggest an edit is deliberately very low. It looks to me like things are working.  A new user suggesting edits doesn't necessarily know what all the network rules and site conventions are and so we may well be rejecting quite a few edits early on. If a suggestion is mostly OK, approve and edit; if it makes the post worse, or breaks a more important rule, reject it.  If you think there's a more serious issue (such as vandalism) or think a short explanation from a moderator would be required to set things straight, you can always flag a particular post and explain the problem.

Comment: @whuber: ah, here's an example of someone with rating of 1 editing a post: http://stats.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/79961. Not trying to bust anyone, just not sure what's happening.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are minimum reputation levels to earn the privilege to edit: 100 to [edit CW posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki), and 2k to [edit non-CW posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) (and 20k to [edit tag wikis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)).  There is no minimum to *suggest* edits, however.

The suggested edits just need to be approved by reviewers like you and I.  When you are reviewing edits, you have several options: one that I use in cases like you're describing is the `approve and edit` option.  From there, I just delete the added 'thanks' and approve the rest.  Of course, if the edit is completely incorrect, you should feel free to reject it.

Comment: If reviewers are catching bad edits then the system is working. That is the reason for peer review, and an important part of teaching younger members.

Comment: yes, I had been confused with some of the privileges (I mixed up ability to approve edits with ability to edit). Some of the edits are a little annoying (i.e. neutral edits, where I think the quality of the answer remains unchanged), but that's just the peer review process.

Comment: No, the limit for tag wikis is 5K (else I coulnt edit them)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, check the link. You can *suggest* edits only (& review other's suggested edits). When you reach 20k you can edit tag wikis without your suggested edits having to be approved by others in the review queue.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [gung](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2708/89026)'s answer there are some things you can do if you notice a pattern of bad edits from a user (regardless of their rep).

1. Ping them in chat, if they've used chat before.*
2. Talk to a moderator in a private chat room, and let the moderator handle the issue.

---

*: I would like to extend an open invitation to everyone to ping me in chat if they think I'm doing something wrong.